# My recursive function is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, recursion

I've created a recursive function to find out if current page is a child of page in a page tree.

My function:

```
function is_ancestor_of( $page_name = null, $post ) {

  if(is_null($page_name))
    return false;

  // does it have a parent?
  if (!isset( $post->post_parent ) OR $post->post_parent <= 0 )
    return false;

  //Get parent page
  $parent = wp_get_single_post($post->post_parent);

  if ( $parent->post_name == $page_name ){
    echo $parent->post_name.' - '.$page_name;
    return true;
  } else {
    is_ancestor_of( $page_name, $parent );
  }
}
```

This is the code I'm testing with:

```
$is_parent = is_ancestor_of( 'account', $post );

if(!$is_parent) {
  echo '<br/> No match';
}
```

And this is the result:

> account - account
>   No match

This shows that it does find a parent page names 'account', but it is not returning any data. I've also tested returning a string, but that is not working either.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems that you're calling your function recursively but not returning the result from your recursive call.

Your line

```
is_ancestor_of( $page_name, $parent );
```

should probably just be

```
return is_ancestor_of( $page_name, $parent );
```

Comment: That will not work. Because the first time you call it, it will run into `if ( $post->post_name == $page_name )`. And since it has recursed twice, it still does notreturn any sensible data.

Comment: Solved it. By removing `if ( $post->post_name == $page_name )` and adding `return true;` at the bottom of the function solved it :) Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

Try echoing `$parent->post_name` just before the following line, and you might get a better understanding of what is happening.

```
 if ( $parent->post_name == $page_name ){
```